# How to write a gulp task to deploy my angularjs app to amazon s3 ?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, gulp

I have following Angular project structure

[image: Gulp project structure]

I am new to creating gulp tasks. I tried for some simple projects and that worked fine but for this project, I am facing a lot of issues. I am unable to figure out the way to write a gulp task for this app structure. 
This project I have to deploy on AWS S3 so for that I need it to build and deploy. 
It would be really helpfull for me if anyone could guide me on this.

Comment: How about this npm package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-s3-upload

Comment: @OluwafemiSule before that I have to write gulp tasks first. I am using gulp-s3 package to do the s3 deployment.

Comment: Have you consider use Ansible instead of a gulp task?

Comment: @Kalamarico no i have never worked on Ansible. Right now considering gulp only.

Comment: Ok, i have no idea to do it with gulp but i think the best way to do an automatic deployment in a AWS instance is with Ansible, it's very simple and you will find lots of examples in google. I hope you will find help to do that with gulp!

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to build and deploy AngularJs application using gulp :
Prerequisites :

- Install Nodejs 6.9.3.
- check you npm version using "npm -v" in the command prompt.
- Install gulp using "npm install -g gulp".
- Set your environment  variables for windows.
- Add the below code snippet

```
gulp.task("js", function() {
 return gulp
   .src([
          "./dev/libs/angular/angular.1.4.5.min.js",
          "./dev/libs/angular/angular-animate.1.4.5.min.js"
     ])
     .pipe(concat("scripts.js"))
     .pipe(hash({
             "format": "{name}_{size}.js"
       }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("PATH_FOR_BUILD"));         
});
```

For more details [Angular JS - Build & deploy using gulp](http://www.tutorial-points.com/2018/11/angular-js-build-deploy-using-gulp.html)